# Is it good to add 'I believe' at the beginning of the sentence?

Tags: sentence

> I believe that people should eat apples.

or,

> People should eat apples.

Which one is best, or when to use which? Is it good to say 'I believe' or 'We believe' in public speaking or public statement?

Another example:

> We believe that every user deserves good socks.

versus

> Every user deserves good socks.

Comment: I believe this question is Off Topic (unclear, lacks research, proofreading, opinion-based, etc.).

Comment: @FumbleFingers research or proofreading what? I gave two examples of some sentences and I want to know which one is best to use in public speaking or public statement.

Comment: @AMahdy It's not really answerable. "Which one is best" needs a definition of "best". Adding "I believe" or other qualifiers softens what you're stating, from sure truth to somewhat more uncertain personal belief. Is that better? Nobody can answer that.

Comment: Assuming you do actually know what ***We believe*** means, ***I think*** asking whether it's a good idea to preface any given statement with those words is essentially "writing advice". Which isn't one of our predefined closevote reasons, but *is* specifically mentioned under ***please, don’t ask*** in [our first Help page.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: It's just a way of making a statement without taking responsibility for it. It's okay, I believe.

Comment: @FumbleFingers are you usually responding in this tone, or did my question irritate you? But thanks for pointing out to the help section, could be more explanatory to your first comment. I reposted [here](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/29497/is-it-good-to-add-i-believe-at-the-beginning-of-the-sentence).

@Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 and @Ricky thanks for your valuable comments, this sounds like what I'm looking for. So `I believe` makes the statement weaker and less affirmative.

Comment: @AMahdy Maybe it passed you by unnoticed, but ***I believe*** in my first comment was partly intended to impart *emphasis*, rather than to make the statement weaker and less affirmative. It's not that your *question* irritated me (I have actually *upvoted* it as reposted on writers.SE, since I do think it's an interesting "stylistic" aspect of writing). Obviously there was an element of punning in that first comment - for which I should apologise, since it's the lowest form of wit. But I did also want to "explain" my closevote, because I genuinely didn't know which specific reason to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no right or wrong answer to this, just preferences and advice.

Using the phrase *I believe* at the beginning of a sentence weakens the argument and implies that the following statement is based off opinions rather than fact. Many people do not include *I believe* in their essays, papers, etc for this reason, even in the opinion sections of popular newspapers.

In order to improve your arguments, use reliable evidence and clear reasoning.

Comment: Hello, Graham. 'There is no right or wrong answer to this, just preferences and advice.' means the question is unsuitable for the ELU format and should not be endorsed with an answer (which would encourage more such questions). This would be a very good 'comment' here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok I'm new to stack exchange and I'm not used to its customs. Thank you for your help.